# where does samba store its passwords?

Tags: samba

I'm trying to make a program that will store the passwords with users input (a web app), rather than having to do it from the command line. The problem is that I don't know where the passwords are being stored as to change then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default Samba configuration on my system puts the password database in `/var/lib/samba/passdb.tdb`. Note that this is a binary database, not a flat text file.

You can tell Samba to use a text file by setting the "**passdb backend**" parameter in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`. But Samba uses a different password hashing algorithm from the one in `/etc/shadow`.

<sub>[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=823531&p=5151903#post5151903)</sub>

Comment: In addition: You can check it with `sudo su` and `tdbtool`. Maybe you will open `open passdb.tdb`. However, you will receive the hex password. So you can only check if a new entry has been added and not what the password is.

Comment: in my case, it's `/var/lib/samba/private/passdb.tdb`